# How do I display variables in C printf() functions?

Tags: c, integer, printf

I have tried to print two integer values in the following printf() function:

```
printf("%s", "The quotient is %d with remainder %d", quo, rem);
```

My book says this should print

```
The quotient is 5 with remainder 1
```

(with `quo` being 11 and `rem` 1), but instead it prints

```
The quotient is %d with remainder %d
```

I am using gcc to compile and running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64 bit).  Did I misread?  Is it a compiler issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken about how `printf` works. Only the first argument is parsed as a format string, and so `%s` is directly replaced with the given string, including `%d`'s.

Correct form would be `printf("The quotient is %d with remainder %d\n", quo, rem);`

Answer (score 1):

Should be

`printf("The quotient is %d with remainder %d", quo, rem);`

The first argument is the pattern to print so you were printing

`"The quotient is %d with remainder %d"` as a plain string (`%s`).

Note that extra arguments in `printf` are just ignored so `quo` and `rem` are just ignored in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

My friend, try this

```
printf("The quotient is %d with remainder %d", quo, rem);
```

The first argument should be the format string. In your case it is wrongly "%s" when you wanted it to be "The quotient is %d with remainder %d"

Answer (score 1):

The first argument in printf() is the format string. when you do this

```
printf("%s", "The quotient is %d with remainder %d", quo, rem);
```

The format string is "%s" instead of "The quotient is %d with remainder %d".

You should do it like this

```
    printf("The quotient is %d with remainder %d", quo, rem);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got one too many format strings.  You should be using:

```
printf("The quotient is %d with remainder %d\n", quo, rem);
```

Note the newline at the end.  Without that, you may not see the output in a timely manner.

If the book has that mistake in it, and if it doesn't include the newlines, then I think you should probably decide to jettison the book and get a better one.

The output you got is what would be expected.  The `"%s"` says 'take the next argument as a string and print it'; the extra arguments (`quo` and `rem`) are simply ignored.